# Creating a kendo-grid with reusable options using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to create a kendo-grid with reusable options using AngularJS?

Besides the default settings, the grid must include a checkbox column dynamically with the option to select all rows . Methods to treat the selections should be part of the directive and, somehow, I should be able to access the rows selected in controller.

Another important behavior is to keep a reference to the grid :

```
// In the controller : $scope.grid
<div kendo-grid="grid" k-options="gridOptions"></div>
```

Below an initial path that I imagined, but it is not 100% working because AngularJS not compile information from checkbox column, so do not call the methods of the controller directive. At the same time I'm not sure where force $compile in this code.

```
myApp.directive('myApp', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div></div>',
        scope: {
            gridConfiguration: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {

            $scope.gridIds = [];
            $scope.gridIdsSelected = [];

            var updateSelected = function (action, id) {
                if (action === 'add' && $scope.gridIdsSelected.indexOf(id) === -1) {
                    $scope.gridIdsSelected.push(id);
                }
                if (action === 'remove' && $scope.gridIdsSelected.indexOf(id) !== -1) {
                    $scope.gridIdsSelected.splice($scope.gridIdsSelected.indexOf(id), 1);
                }
            };

            $scope.updateSelection = function ($event, id) {
                var checkbox = $event.target;
                var action = (checkbox.checked ? 'add' : 'remove');
                updateSelected(action, id);
            };

            $scope.isSelected = function (id) {
                return $scope.gridIdsSelected.indexOf(id) >= 0;
            };

            $scope.selectAll = function ($event) {
                var checkbox = $event.target;
                var action = (checkbox.checked ? 'add' : 'remove');
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.gridIds.length; i++) {
                    var id = $scope.gridIds[i];
                    updateSelected(action, id);
                }
            };
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var baseColumns = [
                {
                    headerTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" ng-click="selectAll($event)" ng-checked="isSelectedAll()">',
                    template: '<input type="checkbox" name="selected" ng-checked="isSelected(#=Id#)" ng-click="updateSelection($event, #=Id#)">',
                    width: 28
                }
            ];

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.gridConfiguration.columns.length; i++) {
                var column = $scope.gridConfiguration.columns[i];
                baseColumns.push(column);
            }

            var gridOptions = {...};

            var grid = $element.kendoGrid(gridOptions).data("kendoGrid");;
            $scope.$parent[$attrs[directive.name]] = grid;
        }
    };

    return directive;
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've put an example directive here: http://embed.plnkr.co/fQhNUGHJ3iAYiWTGI9mn/preview

It activates on the `my-grid` attribute and inserts a checkbox column.  The checkbox is bound to the `selected` property of each item (note that it's an Angular template and it uses `dataItem` to refer to the current item).  To figure out the selected items you can do something like:

```
var selection = $scope.grid.dataSource.data().filter(function(item){
    return item.selected;
});
```

The checkbox that is added in the header will toggle the selection.

HTH.

Comment: mishoo, the problem with this solution is that the default options are configured on the controller, and I can not reuse the grid settings, such as sortable, resizable, pageable, etc...

Comment: It seems you don't think too much about angular scope.
`window.crap = $scope;` :)

Answer (score 1):

@rGiosa is right
I've tried to do that :

```
var options = angular.extend({}, $scope.$eval($attrs.kOptions));
options['resizable']= true;
```

Seems to add the attribute in options object but the grid is still not resizable why?
http://plnkr.co/edit/Lc9vGKPfD8EkDem1IP9V?p=preview

EDIT:
Apparently,Options of the Grid cannot be changed dynamically. You need to re-create the whole Grid with different options in order to disable/enable them dynamically?!

Cheers

Comment: Check below the heading [Rebinding widgets](http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/basics) on how to have the grid watch for options changes. Apparently only one variable can be watched.